# Does it make sense to use the return of a lambda over that of a function when inserting into a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I am trying to use a lambda for a frequently occurring vector insertion to prevent calling an equivalent function:

```
std::vector<vector<double>> A

// There are several loops like this with different conditions
for(auto i(0); i<100; ++i)
    A.push_back(myFunction(
                           lots, 
                           of, 
                           parameters, 
                           including, 
                           index, 
                           and, 
                           condition
                          ));
```

Compared to this, a lambda seems quite elegant:

```
auto myLambda = [&](size_t loopIndex, double condition) -> vector<double> {
                //body identical to that of myFunction        
}

for(auto i(0); i<100; ++i)
    A.push_back(myLambda(i, 3.141))

for(auto i(0); i<100; ++i)
    A.push_back(myLambda(i, 42))
```

The return and body of `someFunction` is identical to that of the lambda.

Is there any downside to this approach?
The reduced number of arguments of the lambda compared to the function suggests that less work needs to be done in handing over data; is that actually the case or does the capturing amount to an equivalent amount of work and we just get nicer readability?

Comment: I guess you should add an extra `()` after closing `}` of lambda to invoke it.

Comment: @VTT: Thanks, my bad!

Comment: Does the code have to be shoehorned into the `push_back` call? Why not `/* code preparing a vector in a variable V */ A.push_back(V);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I wasn't aware the 'naming' of a lambda as in Richard's answer below was possible ;)

Comment: It's not clear to me, neither in your question nor in Richard's answer, why lambda is used at all. What again is the point of the exercise? Why doesn't `compute logic here` simply precede `push_back` call, not wrapped in a lambda?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: That's a good question, I was trying to avoid copying by pushing back a temporary that would simply be moved into `A`, but now that I'm thinking about it using std::move(ref) would do exactly the same if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: Yes it would. Or you could construct an element directly into `A` via `emplace_back`. Or you could `push_back` an empty vector, get a reference to it via `back()`, and then populate it. The best approach rather depends on the details of `compute logic here`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: First of all thanks for the heads up! I edited the question to reflect why it is not ideal to have the `copute logic` typed out before the `push_back`. Since the generation of the vector to be inserted is nontrivial I don't think `emplace_back` would be of big help here, but I might overlook something. Also `A.push_back(); auto ref = A.back(); someOtherFunction(ref, and, so, forth);` doesn't look too convincing to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is quite readable, don't you?

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<std::vector<double>> A;

void test()
{
    // lots of logic here

    auto compute = [&]() -> std::vector<double> {
        // compute logic here
    };

    A.push_back(compute());
}
```

Comment: Wow I didn't even know that's possible :) 
But does this have any other effect compared to a normal function call?

Comment: @mrclng a lambda is just shorthand for creating an instance of a function object.

Comment: But will this stil work if you change things from the `compute logic` the after the lambda definition? I.e. will the captured variables reflect those at the point of the lambdas' definition or at the point of its call?

Comment: @mrclng the `[&]` means "capture references to any variable you need from the outer scope". Have a read here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda